# Recording an IR signal and play it again on Raspberry Pi bullseye

Tags: lirc

I have a Teco aircon with an ifrared remote. I connected an IF receiver and an IF transmitter to my Pi and they are working fine.
EC systems are different to TVs, in that they send a rather long sequence of information each time you press a button. `irrecord` fails miserably trying to get what button you pressed. All it gets is the gap (50000) and the frequency (38000).

I got strong inspiration from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696037/ir-specifying-a-carrier-value-with-rc-keymap) on doing this. So...

First, I record what's being sent:

```
ir-ctl -rTEMPERATURE.txt --mode2 -r --device=/dev/lirc1 -1
```

This is a specific mode, with a specific temperature.
The file is saved and looks like this:

```
pulse 3117
space 1536
pulse 487
space 1093
pulse 487
space 1095
(...227 lines...)
space 1061
pulse 516
space 300
pulse 517
```

I then try and resent the exact same thing to my aircon:

```
ir-ctl -d /dev/lirc0 -sTEMPERATURE.txt -g 50000 --carrier 38000
```

But nothing happens. The aircon doesn't seem to respond.

(Note that I *know* the transmitter is working, because I tried to run the sending and the receiving at the same time, and the receiver acknowledged receiving data.)

I tried different "carrier" options, and none of them worked.

So, questions:

0. Why isn't the aircon getting the message?
1. How do I translate "TEMPERATURE.txt" in actual data (that is, bytes)
2. If I manage to do (1), how do I then send *that* rather than a bunch of pulses?

Am I doing this fundamentally wrong?

I spent my whole week end on this... and am frankly at my wits' end. I will deeply appreciate any hints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding remote to LIRC -- keys are not being added](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137971/adding-remote-to-lirc-keys-are-not-being-added)

Comment: That is a different question about a different program -- and it's unanswered. I guess the answer is no!

Answer (score 2):

Air conditioner codes tend to be very long.  They are nothing like the codes used by TV and similar remotes.

I know some people have had success reading/writing such codes with [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) but it was by no means a simple process.  pigpio is preinstalled in some versions of RasPiOS.

You need to look at the codes being used in detail.

I suggest you have a look at [IR Record and Playback](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_irrp_py) but it is unlikely to work with an air conditioner code.

Use [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) to capture and analyse the codes.

Comment: Is lirc basically totally useless for aircons? Isn't what I did with ir-ctl the same as what you are describing to do with pigpio and ir record/playback?

Comment: I managed to record a key with irrp, but I couldn't play it back. I am not sure it actually is playing back -- if it is, once again, the unit is not reading it.

Comment: I looked at it more carefully, and there is very little difference between the data I get from IR Record and Playback and the data I get from ir-ctl. Well, frankly, the main difference is how immensely precise IR Record and Playback is. What frustrates me is that the unit still doesn't seem to respond, AND no matter what temperature I record the remote with, I always get the same data C4D36440020000000A6 (I wrote a little script that parses the output). I am puzzled.